# For loop in javascript missing a value

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am new to javascript and am learning arrays and loops. I was writing some basic code to change classes of some paragraphs, but am unable to do so.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in it?

```js
function change() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
  x[0].className = 'b';
  for (var y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
    console.log(x[y]);
    x[y].className = "b";
  }
}
```

```css
p.a {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

p.b {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'> b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'>b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'>b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>

<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

As it turns out some paragraphs are changing and some are not can anyone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, which ones are not changing? Do they have anything in common at the time?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a _live_ node collection. Since as you change the classes, those elements are removed from the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` is a *live* collection which means as you loop through the elements and change the class you are changing the collection. It's almost always a bad idea to alter the membership of a collection while you iterate over it. This makes your indexes point to the wrong elements. The easiest solution is to use `querySelectorAll()` instead.

```js
function change() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll('.a');
  for (var y = 0; y < x.length; y++) {
    x[y].className = "b";
  }
}
```

```css
p.a {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

p.b {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'> b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'>b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>
<p class='a'>a</p>
<p class='a'>b</p>
<p class='a'>c</p>

<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Can also use `[...x]` to convert the collection to a plain old array. Variable names could also be clearer.

Comment: as getELementByClassName is a live collection, shouldn't my code work  if i change - x[y].className = "b"; by x[0].className = "b"; so that no matter how many times the collection change always the 1st element in the array will change? But still it doesnt change all the elements?

Comment: No, it doesn’t change them all @DeekshantWadhwa. But notice that it doesn’t skip any. As you change them, the length of of `x` decreases so you never make it all the way through.  Try capturing the length of x outside the loop and try again.